# Suspending repeat() when onPause() is called and resuming it back when onResume() is called using RxJava and Retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-android

I am developing an andriod where I have a scenario, where I need to poll on a API call every 10second. When the user hits the Home button and comes out of the app, the polling still continues and I don't want that to happen. What I need is I want to temporarily suspend that polling and resume it back when the user is back to the respective page on the android.

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have achieved it using repeatWhen() combined with takeWhile().